# Dynamic SQL query based on a hyphen in a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a question about a specific query I'm writing in a `SQL Server 2008` database. This is part of a (much) larger query, but I'll simplify the hell out of it to make it easier to isolate what I'm trying to do.

I have a table `TableX`, two columns:

- `IDX (int) identity`
- `VarX (varchar(20))`

I have two auxiliary tables, `TableY` and `TableZ`. Both have two columns,

```
TableY
```

- `IDY (int) identity`
- `VarY (varchar(20))`

  and `TableZ`
- `IDZ (int) identity`
- `VarZ (varchar(20))`

I am doing an insert into a fourth table, we'll call it `TableA`. `TableA` has three columns:

- `IDA (int) identity`
- `IDY (int)`
- `IDZ (int)`

The IDY and IDZ fields in this table are foreign keys to the identity columns in Table Y and Table Z.

Sounds complicated, but its a really simple connection. Here's where it gets fun though.

So the data in `TableX` might look like this:

```
IDX | VarX
--------------
1   | ABC
2   | ABC-LMN
```

The data in `TableY`:

```
IDY | VarY
----------------
1   |ABC
2   | HIJ
```

The data in `TableZ`:

```
IDZ | VarZ
----------------
1   | LMN
2   | OPQ
```

Basically, `VarX` (the second column), is either going to be a single varchar string, or two connected by a hyphen, no spaces. In the case of a single string, with no hyphen, its always a match in Table Y. The match would be on `VarY` in `TableY = VarX` in `TableX`. I would grab the associated ID (`IDY`), and use that in the insert on `TableA`.

In the example of row 1, the insert into `TableA` would be `(null, 1, null)`

Now in the case of row 2, it has two strings separated by a hyphen. So the insert into `TableA` would ultimately be `(null, 1, 1)`.

So my question is this... how do I formulate the insert with its corresponding joins to deal with this type of logic? I'm sure it has to be a case statement... just having alot of trouble visualizing the full query, as I'm no DBA.... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to make this dynamic SQL, unless the proc this is part of requires it.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (IDY,IDZ)
SELECT ty.IDY, tz.IDZ
FROM TableX tx
LEFT JOIN TableY ty ON ty.VarY =
   (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', tx.VarX) = 0 THEN tx.VarX
   ELSE LEFT(tx.VarX, CHARINDEX('-', tx.VarX) - 1) END)
LEFT JOIN TableZ tz ON tz.VarZ =
   CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', tx.VarX) = 0 THEN NULL
   ELSE RIGHT(tx.VarX, LEN(tx.VarX) - CHARINDEX('-', tx.VarX)) END
```

I have intentionally omitted inserting NULL in to `TableA.IDA`, as I don't know why you'd want to try inserting NULL in to an identity column, or if that's even possible. I have also assumed that the data in `VarX` will not have degenerate cases, such as `'-'`, `'ZXC-'`, `'ASD-BNM   '`, etc.

Comment: Sorry the inserting null thing was just to visualize the fact that the first column was an identity. I am omitting it from the actual insert as well. Couldnt think of how to write it out so it made sense :)

Comment: Also you are correct... it will always either be one char string that matches something, or two sep by hyphen that always match something.

Comment: @optionsix - Sounds good, just wanted to cover the bases for those coming across the question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I changed it, it seems that it can be simplified to this:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (IDX INT, VarX VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @x VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'ABC-LMN')

DECLARE @y TABLE (IDY INT, VarY VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @y VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'HIJ')

DECLARE @z TABLE (IDZ INT, VarZ VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @z VALUES (1, 'LMN'), (2, 'OPQ') 

DECLARE @a TABLE (IDA INT IDENTITY(1, 1), IDY INT, IDZ INT)

INSERT      @a
SELECT      y.IDY,
            z.IDZ
FROM        @x x
LEFT JOIN   @y y ON y.VarY = LEFT(x.VarX, LEN(y.VarY))
LEFT JOIN   @z z ON z.VarZ = RIGHT(x.VarX, LEN(z.VarZ)) AND CHARINDEX('-', x.VarX) <> 0

 SELECT  *
 FROM    @a
```

Comment: I hope you noticed VarX & VarY are both of type varchar(20). I am not sure if assumption of 3 characters works!

Comment: Akhil is correct, my example is 3 char - 3 char, but that's just an example. Could be up to 8 on each side of the hyphen